Methods of analysis in non linear coupled PDEs
I'm trying to study a system of coupled second order nonlinear PDEs with zero flow boundary conditions. The system is given by
$$\frac{\partial u_{j}(x,y)}{\partial t}=u_{j}f_{j}(\textbf{u})+ D_{j}\nabla \cdot (e^{\alpha_{j}f_{j}} \nabla u_{j})$$
But I don't even know where to start. Even if I pick a non trivial stationary, homogeneous state for the non spatial part where
$$f_{j}(\textbf{u}_{0})=0$$
Linearizing around here obviously won't get rid of the non linear coupled terms in the derivatives.
Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Does $g$ have any particular form?

In the particular case I'm studying right now it's of the form exp(-f/u), I could taylor expand it to first order but I'd still be left in the dark about what to do

Nonlinear PDEs typically have to be handled on a case by case basis. Please add all relevant information to the post as it may help users provide better feedback

When you say ‘trying to study,’ what do you have in mind? Are you hoping for an analytical solution for a specific domain, initial values, and boundary conditions; or maybe something more basic like establishing well-posedness, etc.?

I have edited my post to include all relevant information, thank you for tour comments!

What I would like to do is find out the behaviour of the system near equilibrium, I don't expect to be able to do much else, analytic solutions might  be impossible.

As it stands at the moment, your system appears to be quasilinear. Have you explored where an energy analysis leads?

I have not tried an energy analysis, but doing that would require me justifying an energy functional, no? How would I do that if my system is coupled?

f depends on all the components u_j for every j, does that not make it a coupled system? I made a change of notation from what I wrote in the comments, but the eqn in the OP is in its right form. It's essentially an over complicated reaction-diffusion system

It looks to me as if linearizing near $f(u) = 0$ will very much get rid of the nonlinear coupled terms in the diffusion.

If the $D_j$'s are constants, then your PDE appears to be the gradient flow of the functional
$$
E[u] = \frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega |f(u)|^2 - \langle \nabla u, A(u) \nabla u \rangle_F~dx,
$$
where $A$ is some diagonal 4th order tensor. Maybe something like $A = (D\odot\exp[f(u)])\otimes I_n$? If you can show this functional is coercive you may be able to prove some estimates
